# Comparing Data Bound ListViewItems in XAML - WPF & C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a Style defined in XAML that is applied to all ListViewItems in a ListView. The ItemsSource is Data Bound with a property in the code behind (No, there is little to no MVVM in this Application). The Style has conditional Data Triggers. The Style looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IsNullConverter x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
    <Style x:Name="buttonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}, ElementName=lvItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BlurEffect Radius="2"></BlurEffect>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have another Style that enables grouping in the ListView, which looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="False">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In code behind, I give the ListView a PropertyGroupDescription, like this:

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Cities);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Continent");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

What I need is another Condition in the MultiDataTrigger.Conditions, that compares the current ListViewItem's Group, with that of the ListView.SelectedItem. Sadly ListViews in WPF do not have a ListView.Groups property, but I can expose the CollectionView if needed. How would I go about this?

Comment: Only way to do this is to have a MultiValueConverter and then pass your collection view and current item to it and then do the comparison there.

Comment: @Versatile Thank you for the quick reply. Could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue but never updated the question, so I figured I'd do that now.

As Versatile mentioned, you need a MultiValueConverter. I used that, and it looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:ServiceMultiValueConverter x:Key="serviceMultiValueConverter"/>
    <Style x:Name="buttonCommandStyle" x:Key="buttonCommandStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
        TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type res:StabiJobCustomResources}, 
        ResourceId=ListViewItemCommentsStyle}}" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding
                  Converter="{StaticResource serviceMultiValueConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="lvServices" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="viewMain" Path="ViewModelMain"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="btSwitch"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="100"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The ListView that uses it looks like this:

```
<ListView Name="lvServices" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource buttonCommandStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Services}"
              Grid.Row="1"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lvServices_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" SelectionChanged="lvServices_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
                TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type res:StabiJobCustomResources}, 
                ResourceId=SJListViewContainerStyle}}"/>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="auto" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>            
    </ListView>
```

And the MultiValueConverter class looks like this:

```
public class ServiceMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Read values, and set Command binding and content property of Button btSwitch.
        // 0 for selected item
        // 1 for viewmodelmain
        // 2 for button
        if(values.IsNotEmpty() && values.IsExpectedQuantity(3))
        {
            Service selectedService = (Service)values[0];
            ViewModelMain viewModel = (ViewModelMain)values[1];
            Button btSwitch = (Button)values[2];

            if(selectedService.Status == "Running")
            {
                btSwitch.IsEnabled = true;
                btSwitch.Content = "Stop Service";
                btSwitch.Command = viewModel.StopService;
                btSwitch.CommandParameter = selectedService;
            }
            else if(selectedService.Status == "Stopped")
            {
                btSwitch.IsEnabled = true;
                btSwitch.Content = "Start Service";
                btSwitch.Command = viewModel.StartService;
                btSwitch.CommandParameter = selectedService;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `Service` object is a Model with a few properties.
As shown above, I simply compare the values of the Model properties now, and based on that execute some code.